# Name for smart pointer/coding pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, boost, qt4, smart-pointers

Recently I've been frequently running into situations where I needed something similar to this data structure.

**Restrictions**: C++03 standard.

---

```
 +-----+--------------+               +----+
 |node0| NodeDataRef ->-------------->|data|
 +-----+--------------+               +----+
 +-----+--------------+                ^^ ^
 |node1| NodeDataRef ->----------------+| |
 +-----+--------------+                 | |
 +-----+--------------+                 | |
 |node2| NodeDataRef ->-----------------+ |
 +-----+--------------+                   |
                                          |
 +-----+--------------+                   |
 |root | RootDataRef ->-------------------+
 +-----+--------------+
```

1. There are several `Node` classes, where each `Node` holds `NodeDataRef` "reference" (think `shared_ptr`) to the same instance of "`Data`" (class, structure, whatever - dynamically allocated).
2. There is also a "`Root`" or "master" node/class that holds `RootDataRef` reference (this time, think `weak_ptr`) to the same "`Data`".
3. When all `Node`s are destroyed, `data` is also destroyed and `RootDataRef` is set to `0`/`NULL`. I.e. `NodeDataRef` acts like `shared_ptr<Data>` and `RootDataRef` acts like `weak_ptr<Data>`
4. **However** root node can force destruction of data even if there are still active `NodeDataRef`s. In this situation all `NodeDataRef`s that were pointing to the data are set to `NULL`/`0` and `RootDataRef` is also set to `0`/`NULL`.

---

I.e. `weak_ptr<Data>` that can force destruction of all linked `shared_ptr<Data>`.

1. Does this pattern/smart pointer type has a name?
2. How can I *quickly* implement this using either Boost or Qt 4? ("quickly" means without writing a class to maintain list of references)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this pattern/smart pointer type has a name?

As far as I know, no, this is not a typical ownership pattern with a commonly used name.

> How can I quickly implement this using either Boost or Qt 4? ("quickly" means without writing a class to maintain list of references)

There is no pre-packaged ownership policy for this use case, because that would defeat the point of shared ownership. If several shared pointers to a given object exist, by definition those shared pointers have to keep that object alive. If I am given a shared pointer, that's a guarantee that the object will exist until I release it.

If you want one master object to be able to command the destruction of the pointed object no matter whether other objects hold a shared pointer to it, then you will have to figure some separate mechanism for letting it command all the holders of a shared pointer to that object to release it.

**UPDATE:**

Although "hacky" solutions exist to make this work "quickly", I would not recommend you using any of them. This pattern is atypical enough for you to want it to be *evident* when someone reads your code (including you in a few months from now).

Your intent should be made clear through explicit communication patterns between the master object and the other owners, instead of being hidden somewhere in a wrapper, custom deleter, or whatever else.

Comment: I asked for a "quick" solution because I know how to write this one myself, but thought that maybe there's some kind of (already available_ class in boost I could use.

Comment: @SigTerm: OK, I don't know of any "best practice" for implementing this design pattern. I just wanted to point out that whatever solution is chosen, I would rather have it well visible in my code rather than packed inside some custom ownership policy. Good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use `shared_ptr<T>` and `weak_ptr<T>` where `T = scoped_ptr<Data>`. Assuming you are fine with creating `Data` instances with operator new).

The `shared_ptr` should be allocated using `make_shared<unique_ptr<Data>>(new Data(...));`

The root weak_ptr could force deletion by calling `root.lock().reset()`

```
template <typename T>
struct RootHandle : public boost::weak_ptr< boost::scoped_ptr<T> >
{
    typedef boost::weak_ptr< boost::scoped_ptr<T> > weak_type;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr< boost::scoped_ptr<T> > strong_type;

    RootHandle() {}
    RootHandle(const weak_type& impl)
        :weak_type(impl) {}


    T* get() const
    {
        strong_type x = lock();
        return (x) ? x->get() : 0;
    }

    void reset()
    {
        strong_type x = lock();
        if (x)
            x->reset();
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct NormalHandle : public boost::shared_ptr< boost::scoped_ptr<T> >
{
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr< boost::scoped_ptr<T> > strong_type;

    NormalHandle() {}
    NormalHandle(const strong_type& impl)
        :strong_type(impl) {}

    T* get() const
    {
        boost::scoped_ptr<T>* ppx = strong_type::get();
        return (0 != ppx) ? ppx->get() : 0;
    }   
};
```

Initialization of new NormalHandles looks like this:

`NormalHandle<Data> handle1(boost::make_shared< boost::scoped_ptr<Data> >(new Data(4, 3, "abc")));`

Comment: Isn't `unique_ptr<T>` only part of C++11? OP specified only C++03.

Comment: okay, you'll have to use `boost::scoped_ptr` instead then. practically any "scope guard" type mechanism that can be dismissed early will work here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to do this, but here's a (very) hackish solutions which also require some extra code to be run at every access to a `NodeDataRef` (ideally done as a method of that class).

Create a sentinel object along with your `Data` object. Give `RootDataRef` an owning reference to it and all nodes a weak reference. Then, before each access to a `NodeDataRef`, check that the weak reference to the sentinel is still valid. To force a delete from `root`, delete the owning reference to the sentinel, causing all the weak references in the `NodeDataRef`s to become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

One easy to implement (but not the most efficient) way is to have double shared_ptr layers:
**shared_ptr < shared_ptr < data > >**
The root will have a weak pointer to that, and when you want a force destruction you will reset the internal shared_ptr data (do it under a lock!)
All the other nodes will use it normally but have to check the validity of the internal shared_ptr before using it.

Answer (score 0):

No one's given a Qt-specific answer (weird?), so I'll give a crack at it though I'm a little rough with the shared-pointer classes.

It seems that you could generate the `RootDataRef` as a [QSharedPointer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsharedpointer.html#details) and spawn nodes off of that. Upon creation of the first `NodeDataRef`, demote the `RootDataRef` to [a weak pointer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qweakpointer.html#details) using [QSharedPointer::toWeakRef](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsharedpointer.html#toWeakRef). That way, when you delete all of the `NodeDataRef`s, the original pointer will get deleted and the `RootDataRef` should (maybe not?) be set to zero.

If you needed to delete the original object using the root, simply re-promote it back to a strong reference using [QWeakPointer::toStrongRef](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qweakpointer.html#toStrongRef), delete it, and all of the nodes should be assigned to zero automagically.

---

Edit: Alternatively, do you really need a pointer? If this is a case of shared data rather than an actual shared object, you might consider Qt's implicit sharing scheme in [QSharedDataPointer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qshareddatapointer.html#details) and especially [QExplicitlySharedDataPointer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qexplicitlyshareddatapointer.html).